# jQuery addClass when document onload does not trigger child element CSS transition

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

My code is something like

```
$(function() {
    // other codes changing html
    $('body').addClass('on');
});
```

```
body {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
body.on {
    opacity: 1;
}
main {
    transform: translateX(50xp);
    transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
}
body.on main {
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

At first it works, but after changing something else, `main` appears with the status `transform: translateX(0);`

It works in jsfiddle though, so I'm suspecting will changing html of `main` affect the transition? And I tried the following code, it works. Why?

```
$(function() {
    // other codes changing html
    setTimeout(function(){ $('body').addClass('on'); }, 10);
});
```

---

Complete HTML is too long, though structure is simple as

```
<body>
    <nav></nav>
    <main>
        <header></header>
        <article></article>
    </main>
</body>
```

Everything inside `body` is generated with javascript.

Comment: Post your html too

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is that your code is `executing` before `html` is loaded to make sure this behaviour doesn't happen again always wrap your code around [read about .ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   // your code goes here
})
```

**Edit:** syntax issue `xp` in `transform: translateX(50xp);`

```
main {
    transform: translateX(50px);
    transition: transform.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: and another best practice is to put the `<script>` tag before the end of the `</body>` tag

Comment: OP is already using `$(function() {})` which is a shorthand for `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Thank you though the syntax error is only in the question, not in the actual file. Any time delay or any alert before `$('body').addClass('on');` will fix, and I'm wondering what's the best solution.

Comment: but how do you know if the code in the `main` is generated and then the `transition` is added?

Comment: I don't know... I would like to know how to ensure that.

Comment: Can you post the `javascript` too that you generate your `html` with just for the `main`?

Comment: I use this to generate the page, strapdownjs.com, with a few modification